# In OpenAPI, given an array of objects, using multipart/form-data, is there a way to to specify sending each array element as a separate part?

Tags: json, yaml, multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi

For example, given this YAML, how can I get each object in the array as a separate part of the multipart request?

```
paths:
  /grammars/test1:
    summary: Test1
    post:
      operationId: test1
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                grammarList:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      name: 
                        type: string
                      type:
                        enum:
                          - uri
                          - inline
                      grammar:
                        type: string
            encoding: 
              explode: true
```

If that were possible, how can I further "explode" the object properties of each element into its own part? I have tried OpenAPI 3.1 with *explode* set to **true**. In essence, I am trying to avoid using JSON but rather send the array elements and the contained object properties as their own parts in the multipart request.

Even though the relevant 3.1 OpenAPI spec [section](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#special-considerations-for-multipart-content) states the following, I am unable to make it to work.

> In a multipart/form-data request body, each schema property, or each element of a schema array property, takes a section in the payload with an internal header as defined by [RFC7578].

The Swagger editor generates a curl request with a comma-separated JSON object:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/grammars/test1' \
  -H 'accept: applicaton/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'grammarList={
  "name": "string",
  "type": "uri",
  "grammar": "string"
},{
  "name": "string1",
  "type": "uri",
  "grammar": "string"
}'
```

And, the received request looks like this:

```
POST /grammars/test1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
accept: applicaton/xml
Content-Length: 272
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------32ea353bafc67a64

--------------------------32ea353bafc67a64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grammarList"

{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "uri",
  "grammar": "string"
},{
  "name": "string1",
  "type": "uri",
  "grammar": "string"
}
--------------------------32ea353bafc67a64--
```

Comment: _" I am trying to avoid using JSON but rather send the array elements and the contained object properties as their own parts in the multipart request."_ - this is _not_ a good idea - may I ask why you're pursuing this?

Comment: More of an internal spec...